# How do I automatically make roles inactive when case is resolved

Tags: relationships, civicase, roles

CiviCRM Version 4.5.6

Looking at some case types (it seems to work for other case types) where after case status has been changed to "resolved," case roles remain active.

Is there a way to automatically end date these relationships?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Are you saying that the behaviour you desire happens automatically for some case types but not others?

Comment: Yes, I thought that it was doing it automatically for one case type, but after further testing, I'm not so sure.  I'll test further today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after further testing, it appears that the case roles are end-dating the day the case is resolved.

I'm not sure where our issues were cropping up, but this is a fairly new install with lots of data being imported which is where I suspect the issues arose.

Sorry for the red herring.